# How to Slice the external Spritesheet programmatically by using C# in Unity

Tags: c#, scripting, spritesheet, unity

I have a sprite sheet like this: [image]

I am using Unity Engine to develope my game. I would like to load this external spritesheet outside and slice it as Grid type programmatically instead of using Sprite Editor in Unity. 
I would like to find a way to do it by using C# scripting. Because my game would have more than 5 heroes with 10 animations per hero for next updates in my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you use [Sprite.Create](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html)

You would typically use this along with a Sprite Atlas, as setting the Rect properly without one would be pretty tedious.